# What is wrong with my second inner join in this statement

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

This query works:

```
select  rc.[race number],
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty
from 
(
    select  rc.[race number],
            rc.[candidate num],
            rc.[Votes],
            c.[party],
                row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
        from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
        inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

Now, I need to join information from a 3rd table named RACE. I have tried the following query, but it errors out right at my from statement before the second inner join:

```
select  rc.[race number]
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty
from 
(
    select  rc.[race number],
            rc.[candidate num],
            rc.[Votes],
            c.[party],
                row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
        from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
        inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
        from    dbo.[RACE] r
        inner join dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] on rc.[race number] = r.[race number]          
) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Is this even possible? I know I have been posting a lot on this particular query, but I just want to get it right. Thank you in advance for your valued assistance.

Comment: You have the `FROM` keyword twice. So replace `FROM dbo.[RACE] r` with `INNER JOIN dbo.[RACE] r ON r.[race number] = rc.[race number]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes query as below

```
select  rc.[race number]
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty
from 
(
select  rc.[race number],
        rc.[candidate num],
        rc.[Votes],
        c.[party],
            row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
    from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
    inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
    inner join dbo.[RACE] r
     on rc.[race number] = r.[race number]          
) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'. I also tried to query one of the elements from the third table.

Comment: I think I am getting it.  Thank you soooo much!